Azure Bicep reference existing resources from different subscriptions using ternary operators inside scope property
In my bicep file I am trying to reference an existing applicationInsights. Problem is that the referenced application insights changes depending on input parameters.
There are 3 possible modules that can be referenced and each of them is in different subscription and resource group.
param prefix string = ''
@allowed([
  'dev'
  'test'
  'prod'
])
@description('Deployment environment type.')
param deploymentEnvironment string

var isProd = deploymentEnvironment == 'prod'
var isTest = deploymentEnvironment == 'dev'
var usingExistingAin = prefix == 'mrax' && (isProd || isTest)
var prodOrTestlabNameTest = isProd ? 'appInsightsName1' : 'appInsightsName2'
var subscriptionIdTest = usingExistingAin ? (isProd && usingExistingAin ? 'subscriptionID1' : 'subscriptionID2') : subscription().id


resource applicationInsightsResource 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' existing = {
    name: usingExistingAin ? prodOrTestlabNameTest : appInsightsName 
    scope: resourceGroup(subscriptionIdTest, rsgNameTest)
}

(The condition isTest is correct even tho it looks like it isnt)
Right now I am getting this error:

The resource namespace 'subscriptions' is invalid. (Code: InvalidResourceNamespace)

What can I do differently to make this work?
Note:
I dont want to do this using 2 resources approach (code below) because right now this would cause this error

AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client 'clientId' with object id 'objectId' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Insights/components/read' over scope '/subscriptions/subID/resourcegroups/resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components/appInsightsName' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."

param storageAccountName string
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@allowed([
  'new'
  'existing'
])
param newOrExisting string = 'new'

resource saNew 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-04-01' = if (newOrExisting == 'new') {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
}

resource saExisting 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-04-01' existing = if (newOrExisting == 'existing') {
  name: storageAccountName
}

output storageAccountId string = ((newOrExisting == 'new') ? saNew.id : saExisting.id)


the permission issue in your second sample won't go away if you change the approach. you do need to grant the desired permission to the service principal running the bicep command .

why is that, i thought that using the ternary operator approach would allow me to reference the appInsights that I have all the necesary persmisions for.

according to the error message you're missing some permissions: The client 'clientId' with object id 'objectId' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Insights/components/read' over scope '/subscriptions/subID/resourcegroups/resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components/appInsightsName' or the scope is invalid

can you confirm the service principal has all the required permissions?

yes, when testing this issue with my resourceGroups in my subscription I get the error mentioned in the first quote.

I am going to mark this as an answer to my question, even tho I feel like this is a deeper issue with bicep validation.
What I failed to notice in my depoloyment is that different environments (determined by prefix) use different subscriptions.
This means that I did not need to use subscription to set my scope.
Code bellow worked

scope: resourceGroup(resourceGroupName)

